# how to redirect chrome-extension:// page to http(s):// page programmatically

Tags: redirect, google-chrome-extension

How can I programmatically redirect from a chrome-extension page to an https page?

###### Code

In my opened extension page (`chrome-extension://abcdef123.../page.html`)

```js
window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com'
```

###### Expected behavior:

I expected the page to redirect to `https://www.google.com`

###### Actual behavior:

The page redirected to `chrome-extension://abcdef123.../page.html`

How can I achieve the expected behavior?

Comment: Just make the JavaScript described in html a separate file.

Comment: I get the same behavior when the JavaScript is loaded from a separate file

Comment: Why would a separate file make a difference?

Comment: The popup cannot be redirected (use an iframe inside instead), otherwise the posted code is correct, so maybe your actual code has a typo/mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified that this extension works fine.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```html
<html>
<body>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```js
chrome.tabs.create({ url: "index.html" });
```

index.html

```html
<html>
<body>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```js
window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com'
```